# Autodesk ACC API Error 400: One or more input values in the request were bad - PATCH projects/:project_id/items/:item_id

Tags: postman, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-construction-cloud, workato

I want to send a PATCH request using Autodesk Construction Cloud (ACC) API using Workato to update an attribute of a file/document (E.g.: displayName) but keep encounter a 400 error:

`One or more input values in the request were bad\",\"detail\":\"Request input is invalid for this operation.`

to refer to the image below of the error:

[Error 400: One or more input values in the request were bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVmBx.png)

but referring to the [ACC api documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-PATCH/)

I'm already doing it as per the documentation still encounter 400 error no matter what

Below is the screenshot of how I do the PATCH request in Postman which still also encounter the 400 error:

[Sending a patch request but encounter 400 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5At8p.png)

[Headers for the request in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7mTV.png)

```
curl -v
'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/items/:item_id'  
-X 'PATCH'  
-H 'Authorization: Bearer AuIPTf4KYLTYGVnOHQ0cuolwCW2a'  
-H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json'  
-d '{
        "jsonapi": {
          "version": "1.0"
        },
        "data": {
          "type": "items",
          "id": ":item_id",
          "attributes": {
            "displayName": "new name for drawing.dwg"
          }
        }
      }'
```

What is the correct way to do the PATCH request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, renaming via the PATCH endpoint doesn't support BIM360 & ACC files. To do so, please use the POST version instead.

```bash
curl --location 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/{{projectId}}/versions?copyFrom={{encodedVerionId}}' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ...' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json' \
--data '{
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "versions",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "newName"
    }
  }
}'
```

**Note.** Both `name` and `displayName` will be updated to the `newName`.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47564036/7745569
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46474019/7745569

Comment: It works. Yes I am able to update attributes using POST as per your answer. Although it still confuses me why in documentation itself said that it support ACC. Thank you!

Comment: This endpoint indeed works with ACC, but we just cannot use it to change the file names. It supports changing folder names with this endpoint.